# Spamassassin is running but terminal showing "command not found"

Tags: centos, spamassassin

I'm running CentOS 6 with cPanel and Exim. Spamassassin headers are showing up in email but I can't use spamassassin commands in terminal.

```
# spamassassin
-bash: spamassassin: command not found
# spamd
-bash: spamd: command not found
```

I have tried running as root as well.

I have tried restarting exim and spamd, and it successfully shows shutting down of the services.

Should I try to install via yum? I'm afraid to end up with 2 copies of the software.

Thank you for any solutions.

EDIT: Alos, sa-learn commands returning not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably just not in your `$PATH` environment variable. Find them with

```
find / -name spamassassin
```

then invoke using the full path and/or add the folder to `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

As root, execute the cpanel script that will identify the spamassassin path for you.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/get_spamassassin_bin_location
```

Running CentOS 6.5 my executable is located here:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/bin/spamassassin
```

You can also get a lot of good information about where spamassassin "stuff" lives by running

```
locate spamassassin
```